# Explanation for Scaled Symmetric Random Walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, random-walk

If a Scaled Random Walk is given by:

$$W^{(n)}(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt n} M_{nt}$$

where 
$$M_{nt} = \sum_{j=1}^{nt}X_j$$

and the Random Walk is being generated by repeated coin tosses.

Could someone give a quick explanation of how exactly the scaling is being done please? (With realized examples of $n$ and $t$)

Comment: Assuming $X_j = \pm 1$ with equal probability.  Then $E W^{(n)}(t) = 0$ and $\operatorname{Var}W^{(n)}(t) =t$, so as $n\to\infty$ the $W^(n)$ trajectories are converging to Brownian motion.  The $t=1$ case sort of covers the classical CLT.  In short: the $\sqrt n$ scaling is what's needed to get a Gaussian, CLT, Brownian limit.